# In how many ways we can take input values in C++?

Tags: c++, user-input

How to take input values in C++, in how many ways we can take input values.? Please describe in brief with small examples

Comment: You need to read a good book. And somebody upvoted too. :P

Comment: 1. Record mouse movement, interpret as Morse.
2. Check existence of a file at a fixed interval. User can move/restore the file to indicate zeroes and ones.
3. Check the state of Caps/Scroll/Num lock. Interpret as a 3-bit number.

Comment: i still dont undertsand why this post is closed, i just posted a question that i found difficult , sorry if it was a dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For console application you have two standard ways:

1. [Argument values](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html).
2. [User input](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/).

Answer (score 2):

For a command line application, I think the best way is to use the command line arguments. For an GUI application build using some libarary you can always have forms. And the bad way would be to ask questions to user once the application start!

Comment: "And the bad way would be to ask questions to user once the application start!" So, when is the right moment to ask for user input, after program termination? Or do you mean posing questions via speech synthesis in a monotone, robotic voice? Please clarify!

Comment: @Greg what i was referring to was use of text questions. For example, you run a application named 'add' and press enter.. Its asks you "Enter first number:" then "Enter second number" etc.. that is really bad way!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cin >> likethis;
              :P

(Sorry.Couldn't control)